# Google Maps - can't click on marker in my styled map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker

i've been looking for a way to add a 100% width and specific map, that has some styling on and shows the marker for the address.

i found an example that Google Maps APIs page provides ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple ) and applied some styles to it. if i get Google's entire code and save it in it's own html file, it works prefect. however, when i send this code to my complete page, it won't let me click on the marker!

this is the address i'm using for testing now: http://uno.ag/contato5.html

any ideias?

thank you in advance! ;)

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.582423, -46.641885);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
    styles: [{featureType:"landscape",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{lightness:65},{visibility:"on"}]},{featureType:"poi",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{lightness:51},{visibility:"simplified"}]},{featureType:"road.highway",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{visibility:"simplified"}]},{featureType:"road.arterial",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{lightness:30},{visibility:"on"}]},{featureType:"road.local",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{lightness:40},{visibility:"on"}]},{featureType:"transit",stylers:[{saturation:-100},{visibility:"simplified"}]},{featureType:"administrative.province",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]/**/},{featureType:"administrative.locality",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{featureType:"administrative.neighborhood",stylers:[{visibility:"on"}]/**/},{featureType:"water",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{lightness:-25},{saturation:-100}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{hue:"#ffff00"},{lightness:-25},{saturation:-97}]}]
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content" style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:15px;margin-right:5px;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<br /><br /><img src="http://uno.ag/img/logo-top.png"><br /><br />'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'Rua Ambrosina de Macedo, 174 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />' +
      'CEP 04013-030 <br /> '+
      '(11) 5579 2062 '+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      optimized: true,
      clickable: true,
      title: 'UNO+BRAND'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wrapper` div is on top of it, making it unlickable. You'll notice you can't move the map either, unless you try on the sides. If you F12, and set `display:none;` on `div#wrapper` you'll see it works just fine.

Comment: OMG JIsaak, it was it!!!
thank you so much! lost more than 2 hours trying to figure it out!!
=]

Answer (score 0):

On inspecting your code, it seems the problem is you #wrapper container.

```
<div id="wrapper">
....
</div>
```

remove it and the marker becomes clickable.

**Updates:**

I would suggest to remove `height: auto !important;` in your styles of `#wrapper` this will fix the problem rather than setting the `z-index` and always be [careful in using `!important`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/1671639).

Comment: thank you, Praveen. just added a simple z-index to the map div and it all worked! i've never used Google Maps API before, i tought it was something very hard i couldn't figure out. but it was just a dumb mistake hehehe. ;)